# Remove down voted songs

Tags: google-play-music

When putting music on my phone, I blindly added some albums, but I don't necessarily like *all* of the songs on the album.  My solution has been to simply down vote the songs I don't want as they play.

I know realize that those songs are still on my phone, just taking up space.  Is there a way to find these songs easily so that I can delete them?

I've tried using a playlist manager to create a smart playlist, but rating wasn't a filter option.

Comment: Have you tried a file manger?

Comment: @RyanNoles, do you have one to suggest that can read metadata one media files?

Comment: Try "File Viewer for Android"

Comment: There's no way to search for files.  It just lists files.  I can long-press on a single file and get options, but I need to find media files with a downvote.

Comment: What about "root explorer"? It can search for files

Comment: @RyanNoles I feel like you're just guessing now.  Regardless, Root Explorer is a paid app, and it looks like it requires my phone to be rooted, which it isn't.  I'm not going to pay for an app that *might* work.